# Why is thinking not considered as work?

Tags: energy, work, biophysics

While thinking the impulse in our neurons displace and they move in direction of force applied on them. Here the force is applied and impulse moves in direction of force ie it is displaced. Then, why is thinking not considered as a work?

Comment: Not considered by whom?

Comment: "While thinking the impulse in our neurons displace and they move in direction of force applied on them" this is wrong

Comment: I don't see the need for down voting or closing. This is a good question, if a little unclear.

Comment: Neurons don't move, they pass a signal along the chain.

Comment: @mmesser314: some people would consider an "unclear" question as *bad*, rather than good (but to each their own, including their vote).

Comment: @KyleKanos - Understood. But if you don't understand how the brain works well enough to ask a clear question, you still should be able to ask. This question shows some thought.

Comment: @mmesser314: Well anyone *can* ask a question, there's no restriction on that. But just asking & thinking a little bit doesn't guarantee a good question or an upvote-derserving one (NB: not advocating for it, just pointing out that there are valid reasons to downvote this question). OP could use to clarify *why* they think the brain does no work.

Comment: Considering the energy requirements of the brain it's pretty obvious that thinking is work.

Comment: if thinking is working beeing a gas is working

Answer (score 4):

That's not quite how the brain works. Not a lot of mass actually moves, but the electrical impulses with which neurons communicate require the repetitive movement of electrical charge against differences in electrical potential, and that takes work.

In fact, the human brain requires significant energy to do its job. Quoting from

> Appraising the brain's energy budget. M.E. Raichle and D.A. Gusnard. [*PNAS* **99**, 10237 (2002)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.172399499),

you have:

> In the average adult human, the brain represents about 2% of the body weight. Remarkably, despite its relatively small size, the brain accounts for about 20% of the oxygen and, hence, calories consumed by the body.